# Password policy enforcement when using Active Directory in PHP

Tags: php, android

I have access to an Active Directory that enforces a 2 password history restriction. Any password in the last 2 passwords you have, is not a viable candidate to be set or reset as your password.

My server is window 2003 server, and we enable GPO( password history ) . 
In our test , we can't handle this rule .
But we can deal with other rules. ( like password length, password complexity )

However, we test it on window 2008R2 and we get the information from microsoft (http://laviefrugale.blogspot.com.br/2013/01/enforcing-active-directory-password.html).
We followed this example and test it. 
Sadly , it wasn't work. 
(We always get this Warning: Server is unwilling to perform.)

Is anyone try this before?
Could you afford me some advise or ad setting?